Is there a cheat sheet for Seurat data structure?
I'm working on a Seurat data object that has gone through common processing, including NormalizeData(), ScaleData(), and SCTransform() etc.
I find that as the processing steps increase, the internal data structure of Seurat becomes more and more complex.
seurat_object
An object of class Seurat 
79355 features across 44566 samples within 3 assays 
Active assay: integrated (25226 features, 25226 variable features)
 2 layers present: data, scale.data
 2 other assays present: RNA, SCT
 3 dimensional reductions calculated: pca, umap, tsne

For example, after integrating data, I have an integrated assay, but this confuses me. I'm not clear about its differences with data, scale.data, and also, if I need to get scaled data for further analysis, should I use integrated assay or others, or I need to do this process again?
I wonder if there are some concise documents that explain the function of each data?

The github repo has a section for it, but it not up to date.
You can look at it to have a general understanding on how things are stored and then reference back to the updated functions and workflow to see what is put where.
